# Page not found, как исправить ситуацию?

Tags: python, django, windows, framework, django-urls

Решил учиться Django, вот пытаюсь с urls разобраться. У меня есть основное приложение dev и другое приложение sec. Когда в в адресной строке прописываю путь /second? появляется ошибка Using the URLconf defined in dev.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
about/
second/
The current path, second, didn't match any of these.

В settings.py приложение добавил, точки, запятые вроде все проверил, не знаю как это исправить! Помогите, пожалуйста)) Ниже коды url и viewsфайлов, не только Settings

**settings.py :**

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'm@p4e@2rx!kbz-&f0m80ymjcar0*9_=0l=tm6t(rreo7&3rd-#'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sec',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dev.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dev.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

dev/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from.import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.main),
    path('about/', views.about),
    path('second/', include("sec.urls"))
]
```

dev/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def main(request):
    return HttpResponse("Главная страница")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("About US!")
```

sec/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from.import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('second/', views.amin),
]
```

sec/views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def amin(request):
    return HttpResponse("fff")
```

Comment: а по ../second/second открывается страница с fff?

Comment: Совет на будущее старайтесь избегать одинаковых названий если это явно не требуется. Скорее всего вы в главном urls определили  что все пути приложения sec начинаются с second и еще в sec создали новый путь second. Так что предложение комментарием выше скорее всего решит Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

> Решил учиться Django, вот пытаюсь с urls разобраться. У меня есть основное приложение dev и другое приложение sec. Когда в в адресной строке прописываю путь /second?

При использовании `include` вы указываете путь, который будет использоваться для вашего приложения `sec`. В самом же `sec.urls` вы указываете относительный путь.

Посмотрите внимательно на ваши урлы.

```
# sec/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('second/', views.amin),
]

# dev/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('second/', include("sec.urls"))
]
```

**Отвечая на ваш вопрос:**
Путь, который вы должны указывать: `second/second/`